# Reject meeting invitation when already busy

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I want to set up a rule that will decline all meeting invitations if I already have a meeting at that particular time slot. I'd prefer to add a custom message to the declination but that's a nice to have more than a need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more research, I found the way to achieve my goal. There seems to be no way to create a rule that accomplish this. However, there's a setting that achieves the declination (but not the custom message)

1. Open the file menu
2. Choose options
3. Choose calendar
4. Press resource scheduling (all the way at the bottom)
5. Tick "automatically accept meeting requests and remove canceled meetings"
6. Tick "automatically decline meetings that conflicts with an existing appointment or meeting"

In versions before Outlook 2007, the options menu is found under "tools" and you'll have to then select "advanced options"